# What's the best way to move a field out of a Salesforce org-dependent unlocked package?

Tags: 2gp, packaging, unlocked, org-dependent

A few scenarios I would like to test :

- I have a package with a custom field : how can I remove it from the package and restore it as a non-packaged component in the target org, without deleting it ?
- I have a package with a custom field : how can I remove it from the package and add it to another package, without deleting it from the target org ?

The first step (removing/deleting the field) is easy with the `--upgrade-type= DeprecateOnly` parameter for the `sf package install`command (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_install_pkg_upgrade.htm)

But what needs to be done for the second step ?

Comment: For the second operation, this works as expected : create a second package (+ version) which includes the moved component and install it. After it is installed, the deprecated field in the first package is no longer displayed as a component of the first component; it is now displayed as a component of the second package, and is no longer deprecated.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_migrate_metadata.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unlocked packages - move or remove a component from a package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368177/unlocked-packages-move-or-remove-a-component-from-a-package)

Answer (score 0):

DUPLICATE

I found the answer here :
[Unlocked packages - move or remove a component from a package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368177/unlocked-packages-move-or-remove-a-component-from-a-package)

For the first operation :

- in the target org, go to Installed Packages, find your package and open its list of components; removed the component
- then, in your code repo, delete the component, commit, create a new package version and install it in the target org with -t DeprecateOnly